# An inverse problem of cartesian product operation of two graphs

Tags: graphs-and-networks

**Crossed post in** [github](https://github.com/igraph/igraph/issues/2324)

> There are algorithms to identify whether a graph is the lexicographic
> or Cartesian product of two graphs, but I haven't seen any
> implementation of them in the igraph library. In particular, I haven't
> seen any implementation of lexicographic product in any programming
> language.

- A polynomial time algorithm for finding the prime factors of Cartesian-product graphs", Discrete Applied Mathematics, 12 (2): 123–138, doi:10.1016/0166-218X(85)90066-6, MR 0808453
- Feigenbaum, J.; Schäffer, A. A. (1986), "Recognizing composite graphs is equivalent to testing graph isomorphism", SIAM Journal on Computing, 15 (2): 619–627, [doi:10.1137/0215045](https://doi.org/10.1137%2F0215045) (https://www.cs.yale.edu/homes/jf/FS-SICOMP86.pdf)

In graph theory, the Cartesian product $G ▢ H$ of graphs $G$ and $H$ is a graph such that:

- the vertex set of $G ▢ H$ is the Cartesian product $V(G) × V(H)$; and
- two vertices $(u,u' )$ and $(v,v')$ are adjacent in $G ▢ H$ if and only if either
  $u = v$ and $u'$ is adjacent to $v'$ in $H$, or
  $u' = v'$ and $u$ is adjacent to $v$ in $G$.

Given two graphs, it is easy to find their Cartesian product.

```
 GraphComputation`GraphProduct[PathGraph[Range[3]], 
     PathGraph[Range[3]], "Cartesian", ImagePadding -> 20, 
     VertexLabels -> "Name", 
     GraphLayout -> {"GridEmbedding", "Dimension" -> {3, 3}}]
```

But I am considering the inverse of the Cartesian product above.

**Question 1.** Given a graph, determine whether it can be decomposed into a Cartesian product of two factor graphs. For a Cartesian product graph, can a decomposition or a full decomposition be found？

**Question 2.**  If a graph $G$ and a factor $H$ are given, can another factor graph $H'$ be found such that $G$ is the Cartesian product of $H$ and $H'$？

From the [Cartesian_product_of_graphs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product_of_graphs)  in Wikipedia, it seems possible. But I haven't seen any code implementation yet.

> - If a connected graph is a Cartesian product, it can be factorized uniquely as a product of prime factors, graphs that cannot themselves be decomposed as products of graphs.
> - Cartesian product graphs can be recognized efficiently, in linear time.

An equally interesting question is: if the Cartesian product in the above two problems is replaced by the **lexicographic product** of the graph, then is there also an algorithm to implement? It seems that this question is more difficult. Because we see the following statement in the link [Lexicographic_product_of_graphs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographic_product_of_graphs):

> As Feigenbaum and Sch{"a}ffer showed, the problem of recognizing
> whether a graph is a lexicographic product is equivalent in complexity to the graph isomorphism problem.

- Feigenbaum, J.; Schäffer, A. A. (1986), "Recognizing composite graphs is equivalent to testing graph isomorphism", SIAM Journal on Computing, 15 (2): 619–627, doi:10.1137/0215045 (https://www.cs.yale.edu/homes/jf/FS-SICOMP86.pdf)

---

**Edit:** For decomposition of a cartesian product  graph, the code packaged in the link below may help us, even with the Java version. I tried to call it with Mathematica and failed.

- http://imrich.at/books/handbook-of-product-graphs-second-edition/

  ```
  s = Import[
          "!E:/jars/jars/ java -jar 
           cartesianProductFactorization.jar input.txt", "Table"]
  ```

> ouput: {}

We can actually run Powershell on Windows.

[image]

PS:

```
input.txt:

0 <==> 1 5 
1 <==> 0 2 4
2 <==> 1 3
3 <==> 2 4 6
4 <==> 1 3 5 7
5 <==> 0 4 8
6 <==> 3 7
7 <==> 4 6 8
8 <==> 5 7
```

[image]

**Edits:** The answer of Ben Izd is very limited and problems may arise. As Ben Izd mentioned that **this function only works on outputs generated by Mathematica GraphProduct**.

Comment: Looking in the linked by you Wiki article, I read "However, Imrich & Klavžar (2000) describe a disconnected graph that can be expressed in two different ways as a Cartesian product of prime graphs" and a reference "Feigenbaum, Joan; Hershberger, John; Schäffer, Alejandro A. (1985), "A polynomial time algorithm for finding the prime factors of Cartesian-product graphs", Discrete Applied Mathematics, 12 (2): 123–138, doi:10.1016/0166-218X(85)90066-6, MR 0808453".

Comment: These are not Mathematica questions, regardless of the fact that you want to do it in Mathematica. You need to develop or find an algorithm to achieve what you want. After that, you can try to implement it in Mathematica and this forum can help you with that. But the first part is off topic here.

Comment: @MarcoB I agree with you. I don't know yet if there is a better platform to ask this question. But fortunately just now for the decomposition of a Cartesian product graph, I did find the right code, see http://imrich.at/books/handbook-of-product-graphs-second-edition/, even if it is the java version.

Comment: https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/ is a better forum for such kind questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With my limited knowledge, this is a simple draft for your first question that surely can be improved (I think with a little bit of change it can fit the second too).

> This function only works on outputs generated by Mathematica [`GraphProduct`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GraphProduct.html).

```
ClearAll[graphProductDecomposition];

graphProductDecomposition::invalid = "The given graph is not a graph product.";

graphProductDecomposition[graph_Graph] :=
 Block[{size = VertexCount[graph], 
   adjacencyMatrix = Normal@AdjacencyMatrix[graph]},

(* partition adjacency to possible divisors and check for the conditions *)
  Do[
   Module[{partitionedData = 
      Partition[adjacencyMatrix, {dimension, dimension}], 
     identityMatrix = IdentityMatrix[dimension], temp, 
     identityMatrixNonZeroPositions = 
      Transpose@{Range[size/dimension], Range[size/dimension]}},

    If[(* diagonal of partioned matrix is the same *) SameQ @@ Diagonal@partitionedData,

(* find the two matrices and replaced them with numbers to recover the g2 matrix,
 if it couldn't replace with {} which makes the MatrixQ condition fail *)
      temp = 
       Map[Which[LinearAlgebra`Private`ZeroMatrixQ[#], 0, 
          identityMatrix === #, 1, True, {}] &, 
        Delete[partitionedData, identityMatrixNonZeroPositions], {2}];

(* if after recovering, temp is a matrix,
 then it's g2 without its diagoanl which will be inserted with Insert *)
       If[MatrixQ[temp], 
       Return[AdjacencyGraph /@ {First@Diagonal@partitionedData, 
          Insert[temp, 0, identityMatrixNonZeroPositions]}, Block]]];
    ], {dimension, Take[Divisors@size, {2, -2}]}]; 
  Message[graphProductDecomposition::invalid]; $Failed]
```

If it couldn't find a solution, a Message will be raised, and `$Failed` will be returned.

#### Example

Let's reset the random seed, so we have the same graph:

```
SeedRandom[1234];
```

Let's build two random graphs and use the newly introduced `GraphProduct` (in 13.1 is in `` System`‌ `` context):

```
{g1 = RandomGraph[{50, 75}], g2 = RandomGraph[{50, 75}]}


gp = GraphProduct[g1, g2]; // AbsoluteTiming

(* Out: {0.257183, Null} *)
```

Output:

[image]

The output graph has 2,500 vertex and 7,500 edges:

```
Through[{VertexCount, EdgeCount}[gp]]

(* Out: {2500, 7500} *)
```

Using our function:

```
AbsoluteTiming[{g1, g2} == graphProductDecomposition[gp]]

(* Out: {0.844682, True} *)
```

It also works with directed graphs too:

[image]

Your example:

[image]

#### Under the hood

With my basic understanding, the diagonal of the product adjacency matrix is the graph (`g1`) adjacency matrix, and other parts are from

```
KroneckerProduct[Normal[AdjacencyMatrix[g2]], IdentityMatrix[VertexCount[g1]]]
```

So in the proposed algorithm, first we get divisors of the dimension and try each of them to partition the adjacency matrix and check the above rules, if it's true, the first answer will be returned.

##### Update 2022/7/19

In Mathematica, as 13.1, the cartesian graph product output consists of three matrices:

1. `g1` adjacency matrix (for the diagonal)
2. Zero matrix
3. Identity matrix

Lexicographical product has these two matrices :

1. `g1` adjacency matrix
2. `g1` adjacency matrix with 1 as its diagonal

So, for reversing lexicographical product, change `temp` definition, so instead of checking for Zero matrix and Identity matrix for cartesian, use `g1` adjacency matrix and `g1` adjacency matrix with 1 as its diagonal respectively.

Comment: `graphProductDecomposition[RandomGraph[{50, 75}]]` produces "graphProductQ::invalid: -- Message text not found --".

Comment: @user64494 Thanks for your suggestion. Now it should works fine.

Comment: Yes, now the code works well. BTW, a good code is a commented code.

Comment: @BenIzd Thanks a lot. I feel that your code is based on matrix decomposition (perhaps incorrectly understood) and I have been studying your code for some time and still cannot change some details of your code to accommodate the decomposition of the **lexicographic product*8 of a given graph. Could you tell me how to adapt it.

Comment: @licheng You're welcome. I tried to comment the code and added additional info on `Lexicographical`. Although it tries to decompose the graph, it does not use matrix decomposition.

Comment: @BenIzd Many thanks for explaining your codes. Your codes are basing this on a matrix observation after doing ``GraphProduct`` on two graphs in matheamtica.  Now I also understand that you say "This function only works on outputs generated by Mathematica GraphProduct." Actually, a graph to be decomposed may not be obtained directly from GraphProduct (whether it's a lexicographical product or a cartesian product).   Anyway, your codes pretty good, right.