# Test whether a graph is a line graph

Tags: graphs-and-networks

**Just for fun.** **An algorithm implementation problem in Mathematica.**

This question came up when I was chatting with my friend. To obtain the line graph of a graph is easy, but what about the reverse? That is to say, to test whether the graph is a line graph. Moreover, if a graph  $g$ is the line graph of some other graph $h$, can we find $h$? (Maybe not unique. **Whitney isomorphism theorem** tells us that if the line graphs of two connected graphs are isomorphic, then the underlying graphs are isomorphic, except in the case of the triangle graph $K_3$ and the claw $K_{1,3}$, which have isomorphic line graphs but are not themselves isomorphic.)

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_graph) tells us that there are two approaches, one of which is to check if the graph contains any of the nine forbidden induced subgraphs.

**Beineke's forbidden-subgraph characterization:**  A graph is a line graph if and only if it does not contain one of these nine graphs as an induced subgraph.

[image]

This approach can always be implemented, but it may not be very fast. Another approach is to use the algorithm mentioned in the following article.

- Roussopoulos, N. D. (1973), "A max {m,n} algorithm for determining the graph H from its line graph G", Information Processing Letters, 2 (4): 108–112, doi:10.1016/0020-0190(73)90029-X, MR 0424435

Or:

- Lehot, Philippe G. H. (1974), "An optimal algorithm to detect a line graph and output its root graph", Journal of the ACM, 21 (4): 569–575, doi:10.1145/321850.321853, MR 0347690, S2CID 15036484.

SageMath can do that:

```
root_graph()
```

Return the root graph corresponding to the given graph.

```
is_line_graph()
```

Check whether a graph is a line graph.

For example, $K_{2,2,2,2}$ is not the line graph of any graph.

```
K2222 = graphs.CompleteMultipartiteGraph([2, 2, 2, 2])
C=K2222.is_line_graph(certificate=True)[1]
C.show() # Containing the ninth forbidden induced subgraph.
```

[image]

Another example for showing that the complement of the Petersen graph is the line graph of $K_5$.

```
P = graphs.PetersenGraph()
C = P.complement()
sage.graphs.line_graph.root_graph(C, verbose=False)
```

```
(Graph on 5 vertices,
 {0: (0, 1),
  1: (2, 3),
  2: (0, 4),
  3: (1, 3),
  4: (2, 4),
  5: (3, 4),
  6: (1, 4),
  7: (1, 2),
  8: (0, 2),
  9: (0, 3)})
```

Comment: Feel free to [open a feature request for igraph](https://github.com/igraph/igraph/issues), and include all the information you presented here.

Comment: OK, I have put it on the github. By the way, I have also put an earlier question  on there https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/270624/an-inverse-problem-of-cartesian-product-operation-of-two-graphs.

Comment: @Szabolcs What they all have in common is the inverse problem of graph operations.